# Constructing Unions via the LLVM C++ Api

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-c++-api

I'm using LLVM to insert a function where of the arguments is a union, and I'm really struggling to work out how to create the union argument. I can't find anything about defining union types in the LLVM api (the union type is actually defined already in a separate file, but I can't even get the type builder to use this to create the correct type). How do I proceed.

Comment: Your best bet in cases like these is to use `clang -S -emit-llvm` to see what IR clang generates for a given file.

Answer (score 3):

Unions do not exist on the LLVM type level. You must do all requisite casting, byte blitting and such yourself.